# XLM transformation based on XSLT: no exception thown by Transformer

Tags: java, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I convert an XML file to PDF, through XSL-LO.
This process involves a Transformer based on a XSLT file.

This is how I get the Transformer:

```
  private void prepareTransformer(final TransformerFactory tFactory)
  throws TransformerConfigurationException {
xmlTransformer = tFactory.newTransformer(
    new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream(xsltPath)));
```

}

My problem is that if the XSLT is not well formed, then the above mentioned code would **logs** an exception **but not throws** it. This is the output in the console:

```
    System-ID unbekannt; Zeilennummer328; Spaltennummer69; xsl:when ist an dieser Position in der Formatvorlage nicht zulässig!
System-ID unbekannt; Zeilennummer63; Spaltennummer54; org.xml.sax.SAXException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: ElemTemplateElement-Fehler: testcaseDetails
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: ElemTemplateElement-Fehler: testcaseDetails
(Position des Fehlers unbekannt)org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Dem Element "fo:simple-page-master" fehlt ein verlangtes Property "master-name"! (Keine Kontextinformationen verfügbar)
```

As no exception is thrown by the librairy, I can not so easily handle this situation.

Expected behaviour: #newTransformer(Source source) would throw an exception. Is there a way to achieve that?

EDIT: here the full class:

```java
@Log
public class Report {

  private final String xsltPath;
  private FopFactory fopFactory;
  private Transformer xmlTransformer;

  private Report(final String xsltPath) {
    this.xsltPath = xsltPath;
    try {
      prepareTransformer(createFobTransformer());
    } catch (final SAXException | IOException | ConfigurationException |
                   TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
      log.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      throw new PdfReportException(ex);
    }
  }

  public static Report getInstance() {
    return new Report("/report/report-regd.xslt");
  }
  private void prepareTransformer(final TransformerFactory tFactory)
      throws TransformerConfigurationException {
    xmlTransformer = tFactory.newTransformer(
        new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream(xsltPath)));
  }

  private TransformerFactory createFobTransformer()
      throws SAXException, IOException, ConfigurationException {
    final InputStream inFop = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/report/fop.xconf");
    final var fopBuilder = new FopFactoryBuilder(new File(".").toURI(),
        new ClasspathResolverURIAdapter());
    final var cfgBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
    final Configuration cfg = cfgBuilder.build(inFop);
    fopBuilder.setConfiguration(cfg);
    fopFactory = fopBuilder.build();
    final TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    tFactory.setURIResolver(new ClasspathURIResolver());
    return tFactory;
  }

  public byte[] generatePDFReport(final String xml) {
    final var out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final var agent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

    try {
      final var fop = agent.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);
      final var result = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
      final var src = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
      xmlTransformer.transform(src, result);
    } catch (final FOPException | TransformerException e) {
      throw new PdfReportException(e);
    }
    return out.toByteArray();
  }

  public static class PdfReportException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6009368304491510184L;

    public PdfReportException(final Throwable cause) {
      super(cause);
    }
  }
}
```

No exception is catched in Report constructor:
[image]

Comment: @xerx593: I added the full code

Comment: Ty! ...It throws: In `Report(String xsl)` constructor! ..you log it, and wrap it into your custom (runtime! unchecked!) exception... Who-/whatever invokes `Report.getInstance()` can/should try/catch a `PdfReportException` ...

Comment: That sounds as if `report-regd.xslt` needs to be fixed to make sure the `fo:simple-page-master` has an attribute `master-name`

Comment: @xerx593, prepareTransfer do not throw any exception - that's all the problem- so nothing is catched in the constructor and no PdfReportException is thrown neither.

Comment: @MartinHonnen it's not about how i can fix the xslt. What I'd like is to get a clean exception if the xslt is not well formed or anything is missing.

Comment: Ok, believing you/understanding: the error comes only at first `generatePDFReport()`?

Comment: @xerx593: no I think the problem is in prepareTransformer(). While debugging the mentioned logs are output in the console directly at the end of this method call. Without any exception being thrown or catched

Comment: All the logged exceptions are "checked", i can't believe this... Please breakpoint in Report constructor catch block

Comment: @xerx593: I did it already and can tell that we do not enter the catch block in the constructor. This is all the problem.

Comment: I will have do find a workarround, like checking afterward the PDF integrity.

Comment: For diagnostics please try: `catch (Throwable thr)` (all, also unchecked)

Comment: Please step (debug) into `tFactory.newTransformer()` ..possibly something (logs &) masks the exception.